# caculate timespan in a switch loop?

Tags: powershell, timespan

I need to create a code where I find the overall uptime in days/hours/minutes... 
so what I need is some way to timespan each loop and then, in the end, add up the timespan results to got the overall uptime number.

This is what I have so far

```
function Get-UpTime 
{
    param($computername='localhost')
    Get-WmiObject win32_NTLogEvent -Filter 'Logfile="System" and EventCode>6004 and EventCode<6007' -ComputerName $computername | Sort-Object -Property TimeGenerated | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $rv = $_ | Select-Object EventCode,TimeGenerated 
            switch ($_.EventCode) {
                6005 { $rv.EventCode = 'start';$start=$_.TimeGenerated }                
                6006 { $rv.EventCode = 'shutdown';$shutdown=$_.TimeGenerated}
            }

            $rv.TimeGenerated = $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)
            $rv

        } 

}
Get-Uptime
```

Comment: I've looked at this before and it's a very poor way of monitoring uptime.  The logging of the event seems very inconsistent - dump out the event entries in date order to check it yourself.  I found that there were runs of multiple starts with no stops, making it near impossible to get a true picture of when it was actually running - not sure if these represent reboots, but it still makes calculations very difficult, even if you want to assume it is always running until a stop is found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime`?
The result would be in datetime format anyways and it would be easier to calculate.

It would allow you to run the command against one or multiple computers:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName Computer1, Computer2 | 
select LastBootUpTime, PSComputerName
```

Also another hint: Try to avoid processing computers in a loop, unless you do not have some specific requirements. 
If you use Invoke-Command it would process the command in parallel against 32 computers simultaneously (by default), so it would be much faster, than processing serially in a loop.

Hope it helps.

Best regards, 
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using WMI Query:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName Computer1 | Select-Object __Server,@{Label="Uptime"; Expression={(Get-Date) - ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime))}}
```

Regards.